# How do I save two equal objects in an NHibernate session?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, cascade

I have the following object structure (simplified):

```
MainObject
  Person PersonA
  Person PersonB
Person
  string Name
  Status Status
```

Basically, my `MainObject` could hold two `Person` objects.  The `Person` objects will (for this business case) always be different objects, but the `Status` object on each `Person` may refer to the same `Status` (they may both be in status DocumentsUploaded, for example).

Since I am using Fluent NHibernate I get the following exception when I try to save a `MainObject` when both `Person`s have the same `Status`: 
**a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session**.  This makes sense since both `Status` objects are the same.

When I have googled the error I have mostly found posts where it turns out someone got the same identifier in their session by mistake (and I want to do it *on purpose*).

I also considered changing the `Status` field on `Person` to an integer, but that feels wrong (un-object oriented, if you will).

**The question:** Is there any way around this, any way to tell NHibernate that, yes, I know that they have the same identifier, but that I would like to save it anyway?  If not, what is the reason this is not possible and what is your suggestion?

In case it matters;

Here is the code in my repository:

```
public void Save<T>(T entity) where T : DomainEntity
{
    using (var session = _sessionSource.CreateSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

(`MainObject`, `Person` and `Status` all inherit `DomainEntity` and everything works fine except for the scenario described above)

**Edit: Code for loading**

This is the simplified code for loading the `Status` on each of the `Person`s on the `MainObject`:

```
_mainObject.PersonA.Status = _repository.GetStatus(StatusCode.NotSet);
_mainObject.PersonB.Statys = _repository.GetStatus(StatusCode.NotSet);
```

This is the simplied code for GetStatus in the repository:

```
public Status GetStatus(StatusCode statusCode)
{
    return Repository.Query<Status>(x => x.StatusCode == statusCode).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And this is the code for Query:

```
public List<T> Query<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression) where T : DomainEntity
{
    using (var session = _sessionSource.CreateSession())
    {
        using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var result = session.Query<T>().Where(expression);
            transaction.Commit();
            return result.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is Status a class or an Enum?

Comment: I don't think anything is wrong in principle with what you are trying to achieve.  We have some similar code that works just fine. How are you creating/accessing/linking the status object in your code?

Comment: @Chris : Status is a class (which again holds an enum, the text to show etc).

Comment: @fluent : This is during creation of the `MainObject`.  I'm loading the `Status` object with the correct initial status code once for each of the `Person`s.

Comment: Got it. Is the text a constant value that could be moved into a printer class, allowing Status to become an enum & avoid this problem altogether?

Comment: When you say "loading the status object" could we see the code?

Comment: @fluent : I edited in the code for loading the status object (see above).

Comment: @Chris : Yes it is possible to refactor `Status` into an enum.  I considered that and unless someone comes up with a better solution this will probably be what I go for.  Why don't you put the suggestion in an answer and I will accept it in a few days if nothing better shows up?

Comment: Is the problem not the micro managing of sessions? I am assuming you have the same style of session code in your load methods. Are you loading the same status object from two different sessions and then trying to reattach the same thing twice to another session when you save. Have you tried wrapping all of this in one session?  Is this a  web or forms project?

Comment: Some good stuff about managing session from Oren Eini. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx

Comment: @fluent : Thanks for the link, I certainly need to read more about this.  I will try to set up an alternative repository to see if keeping it all in one session will solve the issue.  It is a web service project, there is no need to keep state any other place than in the database between calls to a web service method.

Comment: @fluent : I created a real life test using one session instead of many sessions, as you suggested, and this time I did not get the exception.  It was saved correctly in the database.  Why don't you post your previous comment as an answer?  I'll mark it as the correct correct.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is the micro management of sessions.  If you had one session that covered all of the database transactions I do not believe you would get the issue.

If the project is web service I would suggest that you look at tying the session creation/disposal to the http request.

Comment: Additional remarks:  Loading and mixing so many sessions caused the problem.  Doing it all in a unit of work (transaction) with one session removed the exception.  I will also heed your advice on tying the session life cycle to the http request.